# opening file from string array variables

Tags: c++, ifstream

I'm trying to write a program that will loop through multiple files.

```
string files[]={"file1.txt","file2.txt"};
int i=0;
ifstream fin;
while(i<2){
    fin.open(files[i]);
    fin.close();
    i++;
}
```

This is a condensed version of my code. I get an error from the fin.open line. My complier says: Can't call `basic_ifstream<char,char_traits<char>>::open(files[i])` in current scope.

It work fine if I put in actual strings ie. `fin.open("file1.txt")`, but I want to avoid copying out the same block of code 8 times.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *" My complier says:"*
>   `Can't call basic_ifstream>::open(files[i]) in current scope.`

Older C++ standard versions (prior C++11) want to see `const char*` parameters for the [`std::ifstream::open()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/open) function, you can just use

```
fin.open(files[i].c_str());
```

to keep your code backwards compatible.

Comment: @Arland Note that there's no harm asking for duplicates in general, they can be helpful for other researchers finding the correct solution for their problems. If you think this answer solved your problem, you can still accept it.